# Texture painting logo looks pixelated!

Tags: texture-painting

I have tried to stencil painted the logo on the base color which is just a 2K color image. Then I stencil painted something on top. But no matter what size the image is, it still looks pixelated. Can someone help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your blend file to your post. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Answer (score 1):

Two things that can effect this: Either increase the image resolution upto about 5K or 6K or either try painting directly on to the mesh instaed of painting it in the image editor.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem :-)